# Switch statement in Lisp

Tags: switch-statement, lisp, common-lisp

Switch statement with Strings in Lisp.

```
    (defun switch(value) 
      (case value
        (("XY") (print "XY"))
        (("AB") (print "AB"))
      )
    )
```

I want to compare if value is "XY" then print "XY" or same for "AB".
I have tried this code but it gives me nil. Can some please tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Your parentheses are all wrong, and `case` compares by identity.

Comment: @molbdnilo can you please point out the mistakes. Because i am completely lost with this 'case'. I tried bunch of changes but none of them worked for me

Comment: print("XY")  ? Which programming language is that? Does it look like Lisp? Not really.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`print("XY")` looks more like Algol (and all of its [descendants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generational_list_of_programming_languages#ALGOL_based)) rather than LISP. To apply `print` one would surround the operator and arguments in parentheses like `(print "XY")`

`case` happens to be a macro and you can test the result yourself with passing the quoted code to `macroexpand` and in my implementation I get:

```lisp
(let ((value value)) 
  (cond ((eql value '"XY") (print "XY")) 
        ((eql value '"AB") (print "AB"))))
```

You should know that `eql` is only good for primiitive data types and numbers. Strings are sequences and thus `(eql "XY" "XY") ;==> nil`

Perhaps you should use something else than `case`. eg. use `cond` or `if` with `equal`.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the library `alexandria`, which has a configurable `switch` macro:

```
(switch ("XY" :test 'equal)
  ("XY" "an X and a Y")
  ("AB" "an A and a B"))
```

Answer (score 3):

The [Hyperspec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_case_.htm) on `CASE` says:

> These macros allow the conditional execution of a body of forms in a clause that is selected by matching the test-key on the **basis of its identity**.

And strings are not identical in CL, i.e. `(EQ "AB" "AB") => NIL`.

That is why `CASE` wouldn't work for strings. You either need to use symbols (they are interned once only, thus guaranteeing identity) or use `COND` with `EQUAL` or even `EQUALP` if the letters case to be ignored.